# Bash で JSON 文字列から複数の値を取得し、環境変数へ代入する方法

Tags: json, bash

以下のようなJSON文字列から複数の値を取得し、環境変数へ代入したいのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

$nameにJohn, $angeに30 が格納されるようにするには、どうすればよいでしょうか？

期待したとおりに動作しなかったShell

```
json_string='{ "name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York" }'
read name age <<< $( echo $json_string | jq -r '.name, .age' )
echo $name
echo $age
```

実行結果

```
$ json_string='{ "name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York" }'
$ read name age <<< $( echo $json_string | jq -r '.name, .age' )
$ echo $name
John
$ echo $age

$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一例として、`xargs` を使うなど。

```bash
$ read name age <<< $( echo "$json_string" | jq -r '.name, .age' | xargs )
$ echo $name
John
$ echo $age
30
```

もしくは `jq` コマンド内で `join()` する方法もあります。

```py
$ read name age <<< $(echo "$json_string" | jq -r '[.name, .age] | join(" ")')
$ echo $name
John
$ echo $age
30
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。期待通りの結果を得ることができました。

Comment: jq 内で join する方法を追加してみました。参考にしてみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。jq内でパイプ+Joinできるのですね。よりよくなりました。